# Conformal mappings:general tips

Tags: complex-analysis

Has anyone any general tips for finding conformal tranformations from a domain to another?
For example from $D=\{ z=x+iy | x^2+y^2<1, x^2-x+y^2>0 \}$ to the unit disc. This set is a disc
minus a smaller disc, so what should i imagine to try? If someone could provide his reasoning
step by step telling what ideas make him use certain transformations (also providing some variants,
for example: 'i'd do this because, while if there had been this i would have done that') i 
would be very grateful, because i don't seem to get a general idea of what is happening. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the disks are internally tangent at $z=1$. This looks like a special point for this domain. It's a good idea to map the special point to $\infty$ by a fractional linear transformation. This makes both circles a special kind of circles: namely, lines. And the domain becomes a strip.